# Stored Procedure with multi value parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am trying to create a stored procedure which will accept multi value parameter for the where condition like below

```
ALTER PROC spGetExpectedSalesOrActiveSales @Divisions NVARCHAR(200), @var1 int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM ABC
    WHERE x = '0' and z=@var1 
        AND y IN (@Divisions) 

END
exec spGetExpectedSalesOrActiveSales 'EE, MM' ,1
```

In-place of @Divisions if I use 'ABC' or 'ABC,XYZ' then its working good and 
when I am passing a single value through the API for the @Divisions then its executing that but when passing more than one value like 'ABC, XYX' then its simply displaying no records.
The values I am passing through my API, its an array of string.
I am not taking the @Divisions values from a query but from the API.

Comment: Use a table valued parameter instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to fetch query like this

```
SELECT *
    FROM ABC
    WHERE x = '0'
        AND y IN ('ABC,XYZ')
```

And obviously you can't do select like above.

In this case you can go in 2 ways. One is Dynamic coding and another one is with User defind function.

**Dynamic:**

```
CREATE PROC spGetExpectedSalesOrActiveSales @Divisions NVARCHAR(200), @var1 int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @QRY VARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @DIVISIONS = REPLACE (@DIVISIONS,' ','');
    SELECT  @DIVISIONS=''''+REPLACE(@DIVISIONS,',',''',''')+''''

    SELECT @QRY  = '
    SELECT *
    FROM ABC
    WHERE x = ''0'' AND z='+@var1 
        +'AND y IN ('+@DIVISIONS+')'

    --PRINT @QRY
    EXEC (@QRY)
END
```

Comment: **Shakeer Mirza**, I just did the same but it simply says command completed successfully, and on running the stored procedure it returns nothing. **exec spGetExpectedSalesOrActiveSales 'EE, MM' ,1**

Comment: Could you uncomment print part and see whats happening? Its working for my database table @Saleem

Comment: **Shakeer Mirza**, It prints nothing when I uncomment the Print @QRY.

Comment: i think you are passing Null to @Divisions

Comment: I am sorry I have not observed your Updated Question @Saleem

Comment: this is what I am passinig, **exec spGetExpectedSalesOrActiveSales 'EE, MM' ,1**

Comment: Can we chat in chat room.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132254/discussion-between-shakeer-mirza-and-saleem).

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not support arrays. There are multiple [ways to fake arrays](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/faking-arrays-in-transact-sql/), however, if you really must.

Answer (score 0):

there is something like `Table Valued Parameters` https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/

It allows passing array of elements to stored procedures.

```
DataTable _dt;
// create data table to insert items
_dt = new DataTable("Items");
_dt.Columns.Add("ItemID", typeof(string));
_dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
_dt.Rows.Add(4, "SuperBowl 9 Hat");
_dt.Rows.Add(5, "SuperBowl 10 T-Shirt");
_dt.Rows.Add(6, "SuperBowl 13 Towel");
_dt.Rows.Add(7, "SuperBowl 14 Helmet");
```

then in stored procedure you have something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertItemsTVP] @ItemTVP TVP_Items READONLY
AS
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO dbo.Items (ItemID, Name)
 SELECT ItemID, Name
 FROM @ItemTVP
END
GO
```

read about performace because sometimes its a lot faster using comma separated string than TVP